# AWS - Rollback/Recreate a DELETE_COMPLETE cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to rollback or recreate a DELETE_COMPLETE stack? I want to keep the same ARN for the stack so I am trying to rollback or recreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

However you can salvage the template and parameters that were used in a deleted stack in order to recreate it. It won't solve the ARN issue, but you could have a post process (or a custom resource) that update the stack ARN in whatever script or permission that needed it.